# Sql server 2008 forcing date from dd/MM/yyyy to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-2008

I have a weird problem with sql server 2008. I am trying to save date with `dd/MM/yyyy` format into sql server 2008, But after inserting date it automatically get converted into `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Note : my computer clock format is `dd/MM/yyyy`

My report viewer date text box properties

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQPQl.png)

Date from my database table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wism2.png)

my c# code

lbldate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();

date on report
05/04/2017

Comment: If you're saving it as a Date or DateTime type then there is no format.  Formatting is just how a date is converted to a string typically for display, and is not part of the data saved.

Comment: Also, use yyyy-mm-dd for date string representaion.

Comment: But why its displaying in MM/dd/yyyy format, my computer format is dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: here's my code       lbldate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();           If my computers format is dd/MM/yyyy then it have to store in the same format in the database.

Comment: Your computer has long and short formats. Double check that the short format is what you think it is.

Comment: I have it two times my computers short format is dd/MM/yyyy. I have set it my self

Comment: The only way to "save the format" is to save it as a string or varchar, but in general that's a bad idea.

Comment: Your computer date format has nothing to do with how the date is stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say this is a "problem" so to speak. This is how SQL handles dates. Your computer clock format is not relevant. To change the format, use CONVERT in your queries. Ex:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 103)

Results: 04/05/2017

SELECT CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)

Results: 05/04/2017
```

The codepage arguments are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

edit per your new update: Your C# should look something like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Yes, by querying you can get desired results but i want to display date on reportviewer field

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is the **Data Layer** and as such there is no formatting available; it stores a date as a 4 byte number which is relative to days with 0 = 01/01/1900.

The **Application Layer** `DateTime` type is generally an *ODBC Canonical* representation which basically looks like a class with integer properties for each component (year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds).

The **Presentation Layer** is what you actually see, and that is where you should be concerned. When your application calls the `ToShortDateString()` method, it is calling the display format from the threads current culture, which may or may not reflect the systems settings for *Region & Language* or *Date & Time*.

Solution number one is to set the threads current culture, but this would just go to that particular cultures standard display

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

Solution number 2 is to just use a custom DateTime format string

```
lbldate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is how the query tool presents results and has *nothing* to do with how Sql Server stored the data. Sql Server actually stores dates in a binary (not readable) format.

This is a good thing. Let Sql Server store dates (and other data) how it wants. You only need to worry about how you show the data to users after you retrieve it, and most of the time the best place to worry about that formatting isn't even in the server at all, but in your client language.