# How to return Datetime correctly in WEB API from Database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following entity which has 2 datetimefields..

```
public class Contactos
    {

        public int IdContacto { get; set; }


        public string PrimerNombre {
            get;set; 
        }

        //Code cut for brevity

        public DateTime? FechaConsulta { get; set; }

        public DateTime? FechaArchivado { get; set; }



    }
```

then on my api  I have this

```
  [ResponseType(typeof(Contactos))]
        public List<Contactos> GetContactosDepurar(DateTime fechaInicial)
        {
            var contactos = ContactosDao.GetContactosDepurados(fechaInicial);
            return contactos.ToList();
        }
```

and this

```
  public static List<Contactos> GetContactosDepurados(DateTime fechaInicial)
        {
            var fecha = fechaInicial.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
            string sql = @"SP_ConsultarContactosDepurar";
            return Db.Read(sql, ContactosDepurar, new object[]
            {
                "@fechaInicial", fechaInicial
            }).ToList();

        }

        static readonly Func<IDataReader, Contactos> ContactosDepurar = reader =>
        new Contactos
        {
            IdContacto = reader["idContacto"].AsInt(),
            PrimerNombre = reader["primerNombre"].ToString(),
            FechaArchivado = reader["fechaArchivado"] is DBNull ?  (DateTime?)null : DateTime.ParseExact(reader["fechaArchivado"].ToString(), "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
            FechaConsulta = reader["fechaConsulta"] is DBNull ? (DateTime?)null: DateTime.ParseExact(reader["fechaConsulta"].ToString(), "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        };
```

The problem is that when checking the RETURN values on POSTMAN, the date field is being returned as a number:

```
   "FechaConsulta": "/Date(1459832400000-0500)/",
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to convert the time to your local time using the built in Time Functions. Take your pick from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725473(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If she is returning a Datetime, why on the APÎ response it returns an integer number? her question is how to make it really return a DateTime string, something like 22-02-2017 instead of that integer.

Comment: It's not a matter of fixing the time, it is a matter of displaying it.

Comment: Its displaying a format that is acceptable to be sent across Web APIs. Its a standard format, referred to 'machine time'. its the amount of seconds from jan 1 1970.  
  
If the user wants the API to send the time differently, then they will have to reprogram the code for the API. Otherwise, you must convert the time sent to a readable time format.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass a Unix/Epoch time stamp for the date. I work with Stripe quite a bit and this is how they pass all their datetimes. I adapted my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp).

```
        var myDate = new DateTime(2017, 5, 5);
        int unixTimestamp = (int)(myDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: f she is returning a Datetime, why on the APÎ response it returns an integer number? her question is how to make it really return a DateTime string, something like 22-02-2017 instead of that integer.

Comment: The date that they are getting is already an Epoch value with a time offset, what they need is how to read it in a "human" format

Answer (score 0):

A quick synapses is to realize that a DateTime is just a number sequence and that is how it is handled internally. When you want to see the value of DateTime you will most likely want to format that into a textual representation of the date.

So instead of returning  FechaConsulta and FechaArchivado, you should be returning 
`FechaConsulta.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")` and `FechaArchivado.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")`

For a relative quick reading on what DateTime is and how to work with it, please read the answer I posted on a question about how SQL Server stores a DateTime, how the Application works with it, and how to change display formats
[Sql saving date with incorrect format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784229/sql-server-2008-forcing-date-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy/43785511#43785511)

Answer (score 0):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DateTimeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetDateTime()
        {
            DateTime CurrentdateTime = DateTime.Now;
            return Ok(CurrentdateTime);
        }
    }
```