# Why Datetime format is different in Database and Datatable while executing same query

Tags: c#, sql, database, datetime, datatable

Please help on this,

While executing the query in the database it is showing as below.

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUZlT.png)

and while copying the same query into DataTable the DateTime column form is changing.

[DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2IBK.png)

Comment: Datetime has no format. Only string representation of the datetime has format.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Ok, then how can i copy the exact DateTime string from the database to datatable. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean with 'copy'? As long as you keep the datatype in `datetime`, its string representation doesn't matter. If you want to display it in a certain format, it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Your database is showing in standardized canonical format, and your datatable is showing via whatever the culture settings are for the thread, unless you are specifying a different format.

Don't worry about it. This is how it should be done. If you want a specific format ONLY change it when you are viewing the datatable, and then by using one of the `ToString()' methods for displaying the date & time. Leave your table and query alone.

[Reference on how DateTime is stored, used, and displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784229/sql-server-2008-forcing-date-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy/43785511#43785511)

Answer (score -1):

Database will show data in the ui. as per its culture & regional settings specified while
Dot net Datatable on the other hand would show date formats using Thread's currentUICulture property.

So you have below options :

1) Get your format from SQL server using `Convert` while selecting from table/view.

2) Add a new column in your Datatable & format it using `DateTime.ToString("Format")` method & fill it.

Comment: Both *store* that date in a binary representation that doesn't have any format (no confusion about what part is "day" and what part is "month"). When you *display* the value, it is formatted in a specific way to get from the internal binary form to a string.

Comment: @HansKesting u are right. somehow my thoughts conveyed something else. have modified the answer..